# How to import Baskerville Semi Bold to tex

Tags: fonts

Fascinated by the font of this [journal](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/epdf/10.1086/723392), and found out it's [ITC New Baskerville Semi Bold](https://freefonts.co/fonts/itc-new-baskerville-semi-bold).

How to add this font to the overleaf tex, the closest package I could find is `baskervillef` and `librebaskerville`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The Overleaf website contains instructions on this: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F

Comment: Thank you @JamesT, this is very helpful, problem solved. But there is one follow-up question if I may ask. I tried to change the default math font to `baskerville` by using `\usepackage[baskerville]{newpxmath}` without `\usepackage{baskerville}`, nothing happened to the number in math environment. If I used `\usepackage{baskerville}` the number changed to the font I want but the overleaf method failed. Is there any solution to this problem or something I can look into? Thanks in advance.