# Change the number in math only to a custom font

Tags: fonts, fontspec

This is a follow-up question to the [previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685553/how-to-import-baskerville-semi-bold-to-tex).

I incorporated my text with the [ITC New Baskerville Semi Bold](https://freefonts.co/fonts/itc-new-baskerville-semi-bold) font by setting

```
\setmainfont{baskerville}[Extension={.ttf},Path=./Font/]
```

while number font did not change. I also tried

```
\setmathsfont[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{baskerville}[Extension={.ttf},Path=./Font/]
```

and

```
\usepackage[baskerville]{newpxmath}
```

they seem not working.

For example, the number in text and math now are

[image]

the goal is to make the math number same as text number.

**Question**: is there any simple way to alter the number only to the custom font?

Comment: I think (from looking at the earlier question) that you are referring to the numbers in math, not in the text.  If so, that should be made clear in the question.

Comment: You should give a minimal (non)-working example of code and point out which part of the compiled document does not change, and what output do you expect.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you, the title has been edited.

Comment: @user202729, thank you for the advice, code and example have been added.

Comment: For old engines some copy-pasting and sourcecode-reading is needed [Change font of mathematics numbers - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/change-font-of-mathematics-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1). But maybe there's an alternative with fontspec.

Comment: Maybe [How do I change the math italic font in XeTeX/fontspec? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/how-do-i-change-the-math-italic-font-in-xetex-fontspec) or [typewriter - How do I change the standard "math font"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86785/how-do-i-change-the-standard-math-font) has a way. `mathspec` looks Unicode-compatible.

Comment: Problem solved by [manually declaring the number font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678079/how-can-i-set-math-font-to-a-custom-truetype-font).